# Criptografia de fonte PHP (Sistema)

Tags: php, criptografia

Estou precisando implantar um sistema que criei em PHP, porém gostaria de proteger meu sistema de alguma forma.

É possível criptografar esse meu sistema (PHP) para que usuários mais avençados não tenham acesso ao código fonte e terminem realizando as suas próprias alterações e customizações?

Obs: Não estou querendo evitar copias de arquivo, e sim criptografar o conteúdo dos arquivos PHP e que os mesmos continuem funcionando no site, dificultando apenas as alterações dentro do arquivo PHP.

Comment: @bigown Não estou querendo proibir copias, estou falando de Criptografia do conteúdo dentro dos arquivos PHP, para evitar alterações indesejáveis.

Comment: **"não tenham acesso ao código fonte"** você falou com todas as letras

Comment: Existe uma ferramenta chamada Zend Guard, que permite criptografar todo o seu projeto. Nos utilizamos em um dos clientes aqui na empresa. https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=141&v=dyKvplwwej0

Comment: Também tem um chamada ionCube.

Comment: E tem esse tutorial se não quiser usar usar um programa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvpao46olgg

Comment: utilizei o IonCube em um projeto, funciona bem e não encontrei nenhuma ferramenta que reverte a codificação, o ruim é o preço